# How can i get the data from view fields which are in custom dialog box in android

Tags: java, android, modal-dialog, android-alertdialog

I created a custom alert dialog box in the following way

```
public class CustomDialogBoxForNewEmploy extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    Button ok , cancel;
    String name = "" , id = "";

    public CustomDialogBoxForNewEmploy(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.okButton){
            name = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.employName)).getText().toString();
            id = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.employId)).getText().toString();
        }else{

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_new_employ);

        ok = findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        cancel = findViewById(R.id.cencelButton);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

and im calling it when a button get clicked

```
private void registerNewEmploy(View view){
    CustomDialogBoxForNewEmploy temp = new CustomDialogBoxForNewEmploy(getContext());
    temp.show();

}
```

but now how can i get the data which is in two text views
if i write
String x = temp.id; it will be empty

how can i do this?

Comment: Soo.. u want get out from dialog class string data or use it in dialog class?

Comment: out from the class, but i did it now using interface call back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an interface. Create one interface like below

```
interface DialogEventListener {
    onSubmit(String id, String name);
}
```

then You have to implement this interface in the Activity or fragment from where You are showing this dialog.

You can pass this interface as an argument in the CustomDialogBoxForNewEmploy.
So your new constructor will look like this

```
private DialogEventListener listener;
public CustomDialogBoxForNewEmploy(@NonNull Context context, DialogEventListener listener) {
        super(context);
        this.listener = listener
        }
```

and from onCLick method of dialog, You can call this interface method

Comment: @TehleelMir accept the answer If it solved your problem

Comment: @TehleelMir StackOverflow is not working like that. The reason I told you to upvote is, everyone other gets the idea that the question is answered and the right answere resolved the issue and it is accepted by th OP. This helps other who are facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Add to custom dialog next

```java
public String getName(){
  return name;
}

public String getId(){
  return id;
}
```

And in another class

```java
CustomDialogBoxForNewEmploy temp = new CustomDialogBoxForNewEmploy(getContext());
temp.show();

String output = temp.getName();
```